# Grapecity Active reports - Print with Letter paper , contents gets cut off

Tags: vb.net, activereports, grapecity

I am using active reports with vb.net to generate my report.

When the paper size is "Letter" and scale is "default", the contents on the right side of my page are getting cut while printing.

Other paper sizes like "Legal" are working fine. How to overcome this issue ? Is there any property can I set to make this work in "Letter" format during print ?

```
       Me.PageSettings.PaperHeight = 11.0!
        Me.PageSettings.PaperWidth = 8.5!
        Me.PrintWidth = 14.0!
```

Answer (score 0):

In Reports property dialog, Set (Top,Bottom,Right,left) padding to Zero.it will print all the data without cutting any field.